# Retrieving Data from Model (or Controller) in MVC Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

I would appreciate some guidance on the most appropriate way to achieve the following.

My MVC Application will have a main view (desktop) which displays 2 separate lists (People, Places).  I want to enable the ability for the user to refresh each list independently, without refreshing the whole page.

So, I've created a Controller which will load the "Index" view and pass in a model "DesktopViewModel".

**DesktopViewModel**

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
{
    // Retrieve Person data from database and return to caller
}

public IEnumerable<Place> GetPlaces()
{
    // Retrieve Place data from database and return to caller
}
```

I've create the following views:
Views\Desktop\Index.cshtml
Views\Desktop\_PeoplePartial.cshtml
Views\Desktop\_PlacesPartial.cshtml

The partial views are then included in the Index view.

So, what I now want to do is to add a 'Refresh' button on each partial view.  When that refresh button is pressed, the page should make a call: e.g. Model.GetPersons to retrieve an enumerable list of strongly-typed Person objects, and then I would like to use Razor syntax to display the properties from each Person object in a table.

Maybe, I'm going about this the wrong way altogether.  The initial requirement (one page, two lists, independent refreshing) seems fairly simple and probably a common scenario, so any advice on the pattern I should follow would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at returning `string` and `Json`. A soft refresh is just a matter of using AJAX and calling `Get*()` (which would then be pushed in to your view). You could also return a `PartialViewResult`/`PartialView` if you don't want to perform UI work within the AJAX callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source Code for the below answer](https://github.com/bchristie/StackOverflow-Examples/tree/master/questions-19682946)

Setup your calls that you'll fetch with AJAX (instead of an `IEnumerable<T>` use a `PartialViewResult` (since you already have defined `_*Partial.cshtml`:

```
//
// GET: /Desktop/GetPersons
public PartialViewResult GetPersons()
{
    var persons = this.desktopService.GetPersons()
        .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()); // randomize to make it look like a refresh
    return PartialView("_PeoplePartial", persons);
}

//
// GET: /Desktop/GetPlaces
public PartialViewResult GetPlaces()
{
    var places = this.desktopService.GetPlaces()
        .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()); // randomize to make it look like a refresh
    return PartialView("_PlacesPartial", places);
}
```

(Excuse the `desktopService` it's just a generic way of fetching the data)

Next, add a refresh button and some jQuery code to go and fetch these values dynamically:

The buttons and content:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- we add "get-persons" class so we can bidn to it with jQuery -->
        <button class="btn bt-default pull-right get-persons" data-loading-text="Loading...">Refresh People</button>
    </div>
    <!-- we also add the "persons" class so we have a target to place
         the new content into -->
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center persons">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PeoplePartial", Model.People); }
    </div>

    <!-- same things as above, just in referse order: "places" and "get-places" -->
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center places">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PlacesPartial", Model.Places); }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn bt-default get-places" data-loading-text="Loading...">Refresh Places</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The AJAX:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.get-persons', function (e) {
            var $btn = $(this).prop('disabled', !0);
            $.ajax('@Url.Action("GetPersons", "Desktop")').done(function (html) {
                    $('.persons').html(html);
                }).always(function(){
                    $btn.prop('disabled', !1);
                });

            e.preventDefault();
        }).on('click', '.get-places', function (e) {
            var $btn = $(this).prop('disabled', !0);
            $.ajax('@Url.Action("GetPlaces", "Desktop")').done(function (html) {
                $('.places').html(html);
            }).always(function () {
                $btn.prop('disabled', !1);
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Brad (and others for their contributions).  The PartialViewResult approach feels the most appropriate for my needs.   QQ though ... Whilst I'm more than happy to use the info provided here on SO and code it up manually, you kindly provided a link to GitHub source code.  I've followed that link and can browse the files in my browser but is there a way to download that source from GitHub?

Comment: @NeilW: if you have a github account, just fork it locally and perform a `git pull`. if not (or you don't want one) go to the repository's [root](https://github.com/bchristie/StackOverflow-Examples) and look for `Download Zip` (towards the right). It'll contain that (and a couple other) projects.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModel should not be responsible for retrieving items from the database.  Instead your Controller should pass items to the View via the ViewModel.  Here's an example:

**ViewModel**

```
public class DesktopViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Place> Places { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller** (partial)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // get your data
    var model = new DesktopViewModel();
    // set your data to the ViewModel
}
```

Then in your view, you can access people via Model.Persons.

EDIT:

I'd say you could also do away without using the two partial views and do everything in the Index view, **unless** you're planning on reusing the partials.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should probably return JSON, rather than a partial view.

```
public JsonResult GetPersons()
{
    IList<Person> people = GetPeople();
    return Json(people);
}
```

And then in your javascript, you could do something like (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
$('#refresh-person-button').on('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('/controller/getpersons', function(res) {
        $.each(res, function() {
            $('#person-container ul').append('<li>' + res.FirstName + '</li>');
        });
    });
});
```

And finally, in your HTML:

```
<div id="person-container">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

This is really more for illustration. Rather than manually appending your HTML with .append(), you'd probably want to use a javascript templating system, or something like knockout.js or backbone.js if you're going to be doing similar things around the rest of your site/app/page

Comment: though I agree (mentioned JSON in my original comment) if the OP has gone to the extent of already creating a partial view s/he should really just return the partial again (IMHO). Otherwise, go full-out and just place JSON in the index call (and fetch it again in the AJAX call) then use something like knockoutjs to "wire it up". If you don't, you have UI logic in two places: the partial & the AJAX code.